# Transparent Dialogs in MFC

Tags: mfc

Is it possible to make a dialog transparent using MFC?

Transparent in the sense, dialog is transparent (invisibile) but the content like image or text on it is visible. i am tired of searching many articles on this. help can be appreciated please help :)

Comment: This isn't quite easy to achieve. Can you tell us more about what you are trying to do, instead of your "solution" please?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, under dialog properties, appearance, there is a transparent flag.  Set it to true.

Alternatively play about with the opacity field of SetLayeredWindowAttribute

Comment: @Nik: Of course I have.  I quite often use it - you get a transparent dialog with opaque buttons, unless they too are also marked as transparent.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Something tells me you haven't. Because you do *not* get a transparent dialog. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/12/17/10378525.aspx.

Comment: @Nik: It does imply go ahead and use it and if doesn't give you what you want then do something else.  I've used it, it has given me what I want, which is a dialog with floating buttons and I can see what is behind.  Just reading blogs is no substitute for trying things out yourself.

Comment: Yes i have one image which irregular in shape not in a polygon shape.. i want to make it as a background.. so to achieve that i need to make my dialog transparent.. 

@nik: transparent flag just stop mouse event messages.. and opacity 
will make entire dialog and its contents transparent i dont want that.. i need dialog to be invisible but image or text transparent. i hope you got the point.

Comment: @cup \*shakes head\* the blog post in question explains very clearly why the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` extended window style isn't really transparent. Refuse to read it if you must (although, you should be reading everything Raymond Chen writes if you do Windows programming) but unless you can explain **exactly** what the window style in question means and how it behaves, suggesting it to someone else is a bad idea.

Comment: so any solution please.. iam struck in my project now.. setwindowrgn() doesn't help for me as it cannot provide me curved edges..

Comment: Have you tried http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/bitmapsimages/article.php/c4977/Irregular-Shaped-Bitmap-Dialog.htm?

Comment: Try to search for OnCtlColor(). Overriding that method and putting an entry in the message map for processing the respective message may solve the problem.